# Double tap gesture function is being fired after 1 tap only on first tap, every other instance it requires 2 taps

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, gesture, cs193p

As of right now, when I run my program and tap, I am getting the `println()` message after one tap. However, after the first `println()` message, I have to double tap for every following `println()` message.

I want it so every time I have to double tap (including the first time).

In my View Controller I have the following:

```
@IBOutlet weak var graphview: GraphView! {
    didSet {
        //
        graphview.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: graphview, action: "doubleTap:"))
    }
}
```

And my function in the View is the following:

```
func doubleTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    println("hit twice")

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set

```
gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
```

before adding the gesture recognizer to the view, i.e.

```
@IBOutlet weak var graphview: GraphView! {
    didSet {
        var doubleTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: graphview, action: "doubleTap:")
        doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        graphview.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
    }
}
```

and

```
func doubleTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    println("hit twice")
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Was the double tap working properly after the initial `println()` because that's when the `doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2` got set?

Comment: Yes. That was the problem. Glad that I could help.